# How to get permissions for Gimp

Tags: gimp

I created customized brush using gimp.While I tried to save it in gimp directory, following error is obtained."'C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\brushes\mybrush.gbr' for writing: Permission denied". Please help me how can I get access permissions.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're on Windows 7. Whenever you got errors that you do not have the correct rights while saving items/files you need to get administrator/root access on GIMP.

In windows you can do this by rightclicking the .exe/icon and look for the option "Open/Run with Administrative rights".

Not sure how one would do it in Linux but I assume you'll have to run your program with sudo and/or root access by -su.

When you have administrative rights you should be fine saving everything on the desired location

Comment: Thanks for your response. I installed gimp with windows7 administrator  permision but problem not solved, showing same error.

Comment: The problem isn't installing gimp with adminstrator rights. It's 'Opening' Gimp with administrator rights. Try that, just open the program as an adminstrator (right click the Gimp icon en set adminstrator rights) then open.

If that doesn't work I'm afraid I can't help you any further :)

Answer (score 1):

By default, in Operating Systems where normal users can't create files anywhere on the disk (like any age Linux, or Windows 7), GIMP's default resource folders are installed with the program, and are system wide. These folders are not writable by users without administrative rights.

Running GIMP with administrative rights could, of course, override this problem, but this is not "the right thing to do". What you have to do is go to edit->preferences and on the appropriate Folder resource, create a new folder, this time as a normal user, where those resources will be kept.

From them on, write operations will happen on the newly created folder.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on .exe (.exe-icon) ---> Properties ---> Compatibility ---> Input Setting = Uncheck "Turn off advanced text services for this program"
 - Hope that Help !

Comment: This is unrelated. Why do you think that would help?